# Python: resolving a dependency 'loop'

Tags: python, architecture, dependencies, python-import

I have four modules causing problems.

- `plane` - a 2d array of tiles and a few additional varibales. Depends on:

  - `blank_tile` - during initialization `plane` is filled with these
  - `resource_node` - the `__repr__` method prints a Latin character dependent of the tile 'caste', if the tile type is `resource_node` it instead prints an integer between 1 and 9 corresponding to it's value.

- `blank_tile` and `resource_node` - types of tile, the latter inherits from the former. Depends on:

  - `Data` - they access an instance of `plane` through `data` to discover surrounding tiles

- `Data` - Contains a few static variables that many different modules need to access. Depends on:

  - `plane` for initializing the `pln` variable

This is of course impossible for the interpreter to resolve and in this case I get:

`ImportError: cannot import name ResourceNode`

How can I adjust the architecture of my program to avoid this issue whilst maintaining best practice?

Comment: In general you can use forward declaration to resolve circular dependencies, if you use it right.

Comment: Would be easier to help if you show the code. Design-wise, it seems like `blank_tile` does not need initialize `plane` instances, and therefore does not need to import it.

Comment: It imports the data class and accesses an instance of plane through it. It only uses it in a single function: http://pastebin.com/a3i1vkkE

Comment: Is `plane` a pseudo-singleton here?  It seems to me like tiles either need a direct reference to the plane they belong to (so they don't have to reference it indirectly through data), or else any logic that involves multiple tiles needs to be handled exclusively at the `plane` level.

Comment: @SilasRay There's only one instance of `plane` in a process. Neither option seems preferable - tiles may depend on other variables in `Data` in the future (if I want a tile to replace itself with a blank it'd need to both update the map and corresponding list in `Data`). Additionally there will be many `tile`-to-`tile` functions in the future such as mining, moving from one place to another or message sending. My code could get very messy if these all exist at the `plane` level.

Comment: @Cyber forward declaration seems like the best option so far. How would you propose it was implemented?

Comment: @AshtonWar I apologize, I didn't notice this was tagged for Python, I assumed (mistakenly) that this was C++, Python doesn't have a notion of forward declaring classes

Comment: Tile-to-tile or player/entity-to-tile?  An entity is at a tile, and that tile has a neighborhood, but usually, the tiles themselves aren't interacting.  An entity can get the tiles in its neighborhood, then perform actions on the tiles, but the tiles themselves aren't doing things to eachother.

Comment: @Cyber I think you could get the effect of forward declaration in python by moving your `import` statements in to function scope instead of module or class scope.  This is usually the way to get around circular import issues (no pun intended) if there is no choice but to have the circular import, but usually, there's a better solution that involves rearchitecting.

Comment: @AshtonWar I'm not sure `Data` makes sense.  If you have constants that are logically attached to a class or module (which the fact that you require imports strongly suggests), just make those values attributes on the other class or module.  Also, if you are going through `Data` from `tile` to get to a `Plane` instance anyway, referencing directly from `tile` to its containing `plane` (which is a pseudo-singleton) is in effect just a less direct way to get at the info than referencing directly from the `tile`.  Circular imports are usually a sign of a flawed encapsulation model, so fix that.

Comment: @SilasRay Tile-to-tile at the moment - most entities such as the person class inherit from blank_tile, I may change this in the future to allow multiple entities to exist on the same tile. I'll take your advice and use direct references.